# How to get the last added record in firebase in nodejs lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, firebase, lambda, firebase-realtime-database

I the following lambda function i am getting the data from firebase on adding the record in firebase

```
'use strict';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

let atlas_connection_uri;
let cachedDb = null;

let firebase = require('firebase');

exports.handler = function(event, context,callback)
{


    // var uri = process.env['MONGODB_ATLAS_CLUSTER_URI'];
    var uri = "mongodb://163.172.131.83:28018/harmanconnectedcar";
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    firebase.initializeApp({
        serviceAccount: {},
        databaseURL: "https://harmanconnectedcar-180411.firebaseio.com/"
    });


    var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('testTable');
    starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
        console.log("*************snapshot*****snapshot*****************")
        console.log ( snapshot.val()) ;


    });
};
```

snapshot.val() will give the snapshot of the entire table how to get the recent added value only in the snapshot .

Is there a way to get the last added record or all the records in sorted order

Referred  the following doc is does not help
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query

Answer (score 3):

To sort the query data use [`orderByChild()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByChild), [`orderByKey()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByKey) or [`orderByValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#orderByValue).

Then to retrieve only the most recent value, you can limit the query by using [`limitToFirst()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToFirst) or [`limitToLast()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast) depending on the sort order.

> See the documentation on [Sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) for more information.